# getJSON Loop Performance

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page that is populated with `getJSON` hitting an RESTful API.

Is there a better way to write my code below so that will fire off all the API requests at once instead of sequentially?

```
$(function(){
    var env = [ 'dev1', 'dev2', 'qa1', 'qa2', 'stage1' ];

    $.each(env, function(index, value) {
        var url = '/api/testing/' + value;

        $.getJSON(url, function(result) {
            if (result.date === 'null') {
                $('#database .' + value).text('N/A');   
            } else {
                $('#database .' + value).text(moment(result.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm A'));
            }
         }).fail(function(jqXHR) {
            $('#database .' + value).text('N/A');
         });

    });    
});
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: I'd say performance is moot here; you shouldn't be making AJAX calls in a loop. If you have control of the API, change it so that you call a single endpoint and return all required data in a single call. This will improve client-side performance and stop your server being flooded with requests

Comment: As far as i know, jQuery's `getJSON` is not supposed to be synchronous, so it should fire all requests in the loop, no matter if they responded or not

Comment: A different kind of `async` than Ron mentioned above, this popular JS library called `async` has this method called `parallel` that will work in your case: https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#parallel

Comment: Your requests ARE fired at once.